# Por qué no ejecuta el query en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Por que no me funciona el 2do Query? el primero que aparece en el problema si realiza la inserción de datos, pero el segundo no.

1:

```
$log = "insert into wp_bitacora_usuario (id_usuario,accion,created_at) values (".$cu->ID.",'Log in',now())";
        $rlog = $conn->query($log);
```

2:

```
$sali = "insert into wp_bitacora_usuario (id_usuario,accion,created_at) values (9,\'Log Out\',now());";
    $rsali = $cone->query($sali);
```

me dí cuenta que el segundo no estaba ni siquiera guardando el valor en la variable y le puse las diagonales en el 'Log Out', allí ya me guardaba todo el query y al ponerle un echo $sali, me mostraba todo el query, pero no lo inserta.
La conexión a la base de datos del primero y el segundo query es la misma, pero no logro que lo inserte.

esta es mi conexión:

```
    $servername = "localhost";
    $database = "almacen";
    $username = "admin1";
    $password = "super123";

$cone = New PDO("mysql: host=$servername; dbname=$database;","$username","$password");
```

Comment: podría ser por el id_usuario que le estás pasando sin comillas?

Comment: Pero es un campo numérico, no debería de afectar.

Comment: ¿No será un error tipográfico? En el primero usas `$conn->` y en el segundo `$cone->`

Comment: No, porque por eso coloqué mi conexion, ya que esa va orientada al segundo query, el primer query tiene lo mismo solo que la conexion se llama $conn

Comment: al final de tu segundo query estas dejando entre las comillas un ';' depues del now()) checalo

Comment: Si es la terminacion del query, como se hace directamente en una BD

Comment: Ya me volvió loco esto ya que no entiendo el error, lo copie de uno que funciona, pero este no funciona, incluso intente con mysqli_query y este si lo inserta, pero lo inserta 4 veces y tampoco sé por qué ya que lo tengo metido en una función que solo se manda a llamar cuando sucede un evento.

Comment: no puede ser la terminación del query, verifica bien, el primer query no tiene ese ";" el segundo si, ademas especificas que es la misma conexion, porque usas diferentes variables como menciona @Triby

Comment: porque cree otra conexion con todos los datos iguales, menos el nombre de la conexion, por eso una se llama conn y la otra cone pero todo lo demas es exactamente lo mismo

Comment: si vas a usar la misma conexión a la misma base no necesitas crear otra